# Regular expression to load data from different files

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a VBA script to load the content of 4 colums from two differents files. I want the script to be able to find the file using regular expression on the name. I know that in the title of my two files, I must have either "XM7" or "XM8". so I wish to load the column from this files. here is my code :

```
Sub charge_fiche()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim titre As String
Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim wbk3 As Workbook
Dim Chemin As String
Chemin = ThisWorkbook.Path
titre2 = "run2_tps_nuit_xm7_01062016"
titre3 = "run2_tps_nuit_xm8_01062016"
Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(Chemin & "\" & titre2)  ' jouvre le classeur (titre)
Set wbk3 = Workbooks.Open(Chemin & "\" & titre3)  ' jouvre le classeur (titre)
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A1000").Value = wbk2.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B1000").Value
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B1000").Value = wbk2.Sheets(1).Range("H1:H1000").Value
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C1000").Value = wbk2.Sheets(1).Range("L1:L1000").Value
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D1000").Value = wbk2.Sheets(1).Range("M1:M1000").Value
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("E1:E1000").Value = wbk3.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B1000").Value
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("F1:F1000").Value = wbk3.Sheets(1).Range("H1:H1000").Value
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("G1:G1000").Value = wbk3.Sheets(1).Range("L1:L1000").Value
wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("H1:H1000").Value = wbk3.Sheets(1).Range("M1:M1000").Value
wbk2.Close
wbk3.Close
```

it work for now but I wish to replace the line "titre2" and "titre3" by something like

```
titre2 = "\wxm7\w.xls"
```

or

```
titre3 = [0-9a-zA-Z_]*" & xm8 & " [0-9a-zA-Z_]* & ".xls"
```

but neither of them works. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this works with Dir, but you have to specifie the file path 2 times :

```
Dim wbk3 As Workbook 'fichier XM8
Dim Chemin As String
Chemin = ThisWorkbook.Path 'on trouve le chemin du fichier actuel
titre3 = "*xm8*.xls" 'nom du fichier XM8
filename3 = Dir(Chemin & "\" & titre3)
Set wbk3 = Workbooks.Open(Chemin & "\" & filename3) ' jouvre le classeur XM8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dir` to get filenames with wildcards

```
titre2 = "*xm7*.xls"
filename = Dir(Chemin & "\" & titre2)
```

If there is no matching file, `Dir` will return `""`. If you call `Dir` again without arguments it returns the next matching filename. As far as I know it doesn't support regular expressions though.

edit: you should check if `Dir` found something and then open the file

```
If filename <> "" Then 
    Workbooks.Open(Chemin & "\" & filename)
Else
    'some error handling here
Else If
```

You have to specify the path again because `Dir` only returns filenames, not the whole path.

Comment: ok, it might work, but I'm still unable to open the file then: I get  an errore 1004, because it can't find the file, but the name of the file in the errore message is the real name of the document. Should I still use workbooks.open after the Dir ? like this `Set wbk3 = Workbooks.Open(Dir(Chemin & "\" & titre3)) `

Comment: @NicoBalas `Dir` only returns the filename, not the whole path. I'll edit it in